# Entity Framework 6 Cannot build after adding stored procedures to data model

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I just downloaded entity framework 6 and created a brand new project to test it. We currently use EF 5.

After adding all my tables and stored procedures, I tried to build the project but I get errors:

> Value of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter' cannot be
>   converted to 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectParameter'.
>
> Value of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult(Of
>   DataLibrary.MyStoredProc_Result)' cannot be converted to
>   'System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult(Of
>   DataLibrary.MyStoredProc_Result)'.

I cannot figure out why this will not work out-of-the-box

EF 5 had so such issues.

I am using VS 2012. .Net 4.5 Vb.net (also tried with a C# project... same issue)

Any ideas?

**EDIT**:

The answer was to install EF6 Tools for VS 2012. I did not know I had to do this since I thought that was installed when I added the Entity Framework package.

Comment: IMO, it SHOULD be installed with the EF6 package.

Comment: Yes You are right. You have to install EF 6.0 tool and uninstall older version.

Comment: same thing here, EF5 no such problem. First occuring in EF6.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I guess you are using EF tools from VS2012 which are still bound to original EF distribution (part of .NET framework). EF6 uses out-of-band distribution and it doesn't work with previous tooling - that is the reason why those types has little bit different namespaces and cannot be converted from one to another.

Solution should be downloading and installing [EF6 tools for VS2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40762) or using VS2013 where tools should be included.

Comment: I needed to change the references like in the answer below as well.

Comment: I have VS 2012 Update 4  and I have installed the EF 6 tools from the above link, but it still refrences the wrong namespace...
Ok, now I can update the namespace in my .tt file, but the generated method expects an Array of ObjectResult not an object of ObjectResult.

Answer (score 99):

You can overcome this scenario by replacing:

```
using System.Data.Objects;
```

With:

```
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;
```

You may need to update the `using` statements in your T4 templates, like your Context.tt file, so that auto-generated files continue to work when re-generating.

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

Comment: Wow, that actually worked for me as well. Saved me a big headache! This error originated in VS2013 for me, new project. 2012 never touched it.

Comment: Worked for me, I did NOT have to install the EF tools for VS2012 only made the change above

Comment: I assume this is done in `MyContext.Context.cs` file. This file is auto generated, so manual changes will be overwritten if the code is regenerated..

Comment: @Doomsknight Update the using statements in your T4 templates, like your Context.tt file, so regenerations continue to work.

Answer (score 1):

I used what "Pauly Glott", which worked for me. For a little more detailed info, see my post in Microsoft forums and the answer.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9ac881f5-18f5-4aa4-bd99-94b1fa4c37c2/why-i-am-getting-errors-like-value-of-type-systemdataobjectsobjectparameter-cannot-be?forum=adodotnetentityframework