# EF6 and VS 2012 - Generates faulty code for stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6

I have VS 2012 Update 4  and I have installed the [EF6 Tools for VS2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40762).

Approach: Database First.

When trying to generate stored procedures the generated code references the wrong namespace...
Ok, now I can update the namespace in my .tt file, but the generated method expects an Array of ObjectResult not an object of ObjectResult.

This is wrong:

```
 public virtual ObjectResult<CustOrdersDetail_Result> CustOrdersDetail(Nullable<int> orderID)
        {
            var orderIDParameter = orderID.HasValue ?
                new ObjectParameter("OrderID", orderID) :
                new ObjectParameter("OrderID", typeof(int));

            return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<CustOrdersDetail_Result>("CustOrdersDetail", orderIDParameter);
}
```

and this code works:

```
public virtual ObjectResult<CustOrdersDetail_Result> CustOrdersDetail(Nullable<int> orderID)
            {
                var orderIDParameter = orderID.HasValue ?
                new ObjectParameter[]{    new ObjectParameter("OrderID", orderID)} :
                   new ObjectParameter[]{ new ObjectParameter("OrderID", typeof(int))};

                return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<CustOrdersDetail_Result>("CustOrdersDetail", orderIDParameter);
    }
```

Now I can fix the Array thing manually, but after edmx code generation it will be gone, of course...

I also took a look at [Ladislav's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19661494/entity-framework-6-cannot-build-after-adding-stored-procedures-to-data-model), but with no success:

Is there a fix for that?

Comment: Clearly you still have the old tt files. Try to remove the old tt files + generated code and re-add a code generation item for DbContext.

Comment: Hm, I have made a couple of adjustments in the tt files, this will be some work. What do you mean by saying, add a new code generation item for DbContext?
I do DB First, I add a ADO.NET Entity Data Model and that's actually all I do.
So do you mean, delete the whole model and re-add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To re add code generation item remove all generated files from the model and than right click on the model and select add new generation item. You should never modifying tt files I think there is a way to implement customs generator otherwise on a new update of the generation item it is hard to bring your changes to the new version as all your changes in TT files get lost.

Comment: Actually there are parts which you can modify and they will not be overriden, only generated parts may not be modified, as they will be lost on i.e. update of edmx file.